# The character is rendered differently between Unity and Blender

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, 3d-rendering

I have a fbx character. When I import it in Unity, I have this result
[image]

While, when I import the same file in Blender, I have this result.

[image]

In the second image the are a many polygons and I don't understand why, since the file is the same of Unity. How can I get the same result as Unity in Blender? Thank you.

Comment: You should ask this question on blender.stackexchange.com, rather than here.

Comment: a) Unity automatically always uses smoothing in Unity you can switch between smooth and hard rendering on a per face/triangle basis. b) looks a bit like a culling issue -> check if the normals are correctly pointing outwards in blender

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this before, my easiest fix is to recreate the materials on the model in Blender, unassign the existing materials, and apply your new materials. You could also go to the existing materials' properties and find any anomalies, but that takes some time, and I haven't done that.

I wish I could explain exactly *why* this is happening, but I don't really know, sorry. If anyone does have an explanation, I'll be glad to edit it into the answer.